# node net.socket client still sending data after close event

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I'm facing a problem with a tcp server for IoT devices, I'm using a stream approach implementing a transform class to process incoming data (the device class).

```
this.server = net.createServer(async function onConnection(socket) {
  const device = new gateway.DeviceClass(gateway);
  socket.setTimeout(0);
  socket
    .pipe(device)
```

then on close event I disconnect the stream processor and destroy the socket

```
socket.once('close', ()=>{
   this.socket.unpipe();
   this.socket.removeAllListeners();
   this.socket.destroy();
   this.socket.unref();
})
```

The problem is that sometime the client is still sending data? and I got a closed stream write error. Also sometime it seems I'm missing data that is transmitted but never received?

from the documentation close event is emitted "Emitted once the socket is fully closed. The argument hadError is a boolean which says if the socket was closed due to a transmission error." so I expect no more data is sent over it.